# SAX, XML file parsing error

Tags: xml, sax

when I try to parse my xml using SAX, i got an issue :

> 04-09 18:19:02.690: WARN/System.err(518):
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column
>   0: not well-formed (invalid token)

the begining of my xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<map>
    <line>
        <item>
```

Thank you.

PS : im using android SDK

Comment: Have you ruled out encoding issues (UTF-8 vs. CP-1252. e.g.) as a cause?

Comment: I checked, my file is welly encoded with UTF8

Comment: Continuing on the same path, have you tried displaying all the chars in the file with an editor that supports this operation, such as np++? Maybe there's a non printable char at the beginning of the document...

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that, for some reason, this is NOT the XML that you have supplied to the parser.